# composer не тянет зависимости рекурсивно

Tags: php, composer

Хочу использовать в проекте стороннюю библиотеку, создал `composer.json`, прописал зависимость. В свою очередь библиотека имеет свой `composer.json`, со своими зависимостями. После команды `composer install` тянется только библиотека прописанная в основном `composer.json`, вложенный игнорируется, никаких ошибок нет. Как заставить `composer` тянуть зависимости рекурсивно?

`composer.json` :

```
{
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.0",
        "chobie/jira-api-restclient": "dev-master"
    },
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "git",
            "url": "https://github.com/chobie/jira-api-restclient"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: композер подтягивает все зависимости, покажите свой `composer.json`

Comment: Добавил содержимое моего `composer.json`, библиотечный `composer.json` можно посмотреть в репозитории. Я решил проблему так - добавил содержимое из библиотечного `composer.json` в свой основной, зависимости подгрузило (естественно), но мне кажется это плохое решение.

Answer (score 1):

Для кастомных репозиториев композер не загружает зависимости.
Описание этой проблемы и возможные решения есть на сайте [композера](https://getcomposer.org/doc/faqs/why-can't-composer-load-repositories-recursively.md).

Большинство пакетов уже есть на packagist, поэтому самым лучшим решением будет использовать готовые пакеты.

В вашем случае пакет уже есть
https://packagist.org/packages/chobie/jira-api-restclient, установить его можно командой

```
composer require chobie/jira-api-restclient
```